# How can I use parameters I've passed to my Cloud code in a push notification? (Parse.com/Android/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, push-notification, push

I'm trying to send Push notifications to my users, and it works successfully but I'm not sure how to use the parameters that I pass it in the message itself. I'm not that experience in JS so any help would be appreciated.

**My Android code:**

```
// Send push notification
        final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("userId", userId);
        params.put("result", result);
        params.put("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        params.put("useMasterKey", true); //Must have this line

        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("pushLike", params, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
            public void done(String result, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d(getClass().toString(), "ANNOUNCEMENT SUCCESS");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    Log.d(getClass().toString(), "ANNOUNCEMENT FAILURE");
                }
            }
        });
```

**JavaScript Cloud Code.** I'm just trying to figure out how to include the parameter variables that I've passed into the alert message itself. This doesn't work apparently:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("pushLike", function (request, response) {
  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.equalTo('userId', request.params.userId);

  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
      var username = request.params.userId;
      var result = request.params.result;
      alert: "Liked by " + username + ": " + result;
    }
  }, {
    useMasterKey: true,
    success: function () {
      response.success("Success!");
    },
    error: function (error) {
      response.error("Error! " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Cloud Code to look this this. Pushed the variables up a bit in the code and just used them like normal in the alert:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("pushLike", function (request, response) {
  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.equalTo('userId', request.params.userId);

  var username = request.params.username;
  var result = request.params.result;

  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
      alert: "Liked by " + username + ": " + result
    }
  }, {
    useMasterKey: true,
    success: function () {
      response.success("Success!");
    },
    error: function (error) {
      response.error("Error! " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```